# How to reduce a matrix without losing names of attributes in R

Tags: r, matrix, label, bind, reduce

My problem is the following:

I need to reduce a matrix cutting some columns away but keeping the names of column vectors.
DTM is my original matrix that looks like the following:

```
>DTM
   word1    word2    word3    word4
[1] 1         1        0        0
[2] 2         0        1        1
[3] 0         1        0        2
```

and I want to obtain a new matrix (DTMr in the following chunk of code) that has 'labels' and eliminates all columns whose sum of members is less than a threshold (say 2):

```
   word1    word4
[1] 1         0
[2] 2         1
[3] 0         2

>DTMr <- matrix(,nrow=nrow(DTM),ncol=d) # This should be the reduced matrix
```

where d is the number of columns  of DTM that are larger than the threshold

```
>c = 1 # new counter
>for (col in 1:ncol(DTM))
>{
>  if (sum(DTM[,col]) > 2) 
>  { 
>    DTMr[,c] = DTM[,col]
>    
>    c=c+1
>  }
>}
```

Unfortunately in this way, DTMr is perfect, but it loses all labels (word 1, ...word n).

Any ideas?

Claudio

Comment: actually, `DTMr` doesn't loose anything: it never got the labels...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution using subsetting and `colSums`:

Create some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 12, replace=TRUE), ncol=4)
colnames(x) <- LETTERS[1:4]
x
     A B C D
[1,] 0 2 2 0
[2,] 1 0 1 0
[3,] 1 2 1 0
```

Subset:

```
x[, colSums(x)<4]
     A D
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 1 0
[3,] 1 0
```

Comment: this was the briefest, lovely answer

Answer (score 2):

Just use `apply` and some simple indexing:

```
DTM[,apply(DTM,2,sum) > 2]
     word1 word4
[1,]     1     0
[2,]     2     1
[3,]     0     2
```

Unpacking this a bit, `apply(DTM,2,sum)` return a vector of column sums. The subsequent boolean comparison results in a boolean vector that is TRUE when the corresponding column sum is greater than 2. Finally, placing this all in the second argument of `[` select just those columns.

And as Ben mentions in the comments, `colSums` is a faster (for larger matrices) and more compact way to do this:

```
DTM[,colSums(DTM) > 2]
```

Comment: yes.  `colSums()` would be a hair faster and more compact than `apply(DTM,2,sum)`

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are preserved if you delete the columns instead of copying to a new matrix without attributes

(I'm just using another matrix I have around)

```
> m <- structure(c(26, 5, 21, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
                 .Dim = c(3L, 3L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), 
                                  c("PC1", "PC2", "PC3")))
> m
           PC1 PC2 PC3
setosa      26   2   0
versicolor   5   2   1
virginica   21   1   1

> colSums (m)
PC1 PC2 PC3 
52   5   2 

> m [, colSums (m) <= 2, drop = FALSE]
           PC3
setosa       0
versicolor   1
virginica    1
```